# iOS7 - View under status bar - edgesForExtendedLayout not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I have a project that was built last year, and it uses XIBs, no storyboards.  The XIBs do not use Auto Layout, but they do use some Autosizing.  I have an issue when running with iOS7, in which all the views are tucked under the status bar.  I fully understand this is a new feature with iOS7, in which this can be expected.  However, all of the solutions for fixing it to not do this are not working.  I have an image at the top of the view that always shows under the status-bar, and I'm not using nav-bars or anything like that.

I have tried updating the Y-deltas in the XIB (they have no effect on the view), I have tried setting the `edgesForExtendedLayout` to `UIRectEdgeNone` (does nothing), and a multitude of other things.  Every time, the status bar shows with the view tucked under it, no matter what I do.. that is unless I manually move down the view in the XIB to allow room for the status bar (but that solution doesn't work because it doesn't look right in iOS6, of course).

What's odd is that even when I try a line of code to hack in a view-shift, it doesn't work (like the following):

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y+20, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

..Not that I would go with that kind of solution, but it's just odd that it didn't work (the only time I typically see that not work is if Auto Layout is in place, which it's not in this case).

It is a design requirement that the status-bar shows, and I'm just stumped on why I can't set the view to be under the status bar for iOS7.  I have read every single Stack Overflow post on the subject, as well as Apple's transition/guides.  Once again, to reiterate, I fully understand how it should function and what the expected solution should be to this, but none of that seems to be working for this particular project.

I am an experienced iOS dev, but this project was built by another team, so I don't know if there's something hidden somewhere in the XIB files, plist, or code that could be trumping the above settings.  Please let me know if there is something else that can be looked at on this, or more information I can provide.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hey have u get any solution? i am facing same problem.

Comment: Anyone with solution right there?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you set the iOS 6/7 delta values in Interface Builder, remember to set "View as" to "iOS 6" on the Interface Builder Document, since it is the iOS 6 layout you want to replicate. The deltas will then be used only on iOS 7 to push the content below the status bar. If you leave "View as" set to iOS 7 (the default) the deltas will instead give you the iOS 7 look on iOS 6.

However, the deltas will not help you if you reposition or resize views programmatically based on the view frame, since the frame does not account for the deltas.

Instead of using the deltas, the best solution I have found is to enable Auto Layout on your main XIB and then set the top space constraint on your top/content view to follow the Top Layout Guide. This guide was introduced in iOS 7 and represents the position below the status bar. Unfortunately the guide is not available in Interface Builder when not using Storyboards, but you can add it programmatically.

What I did was add a top space constraint to the superview instead in Interface Builder, and created an outlet for this in the code. Then, in viewDidLoad, if the topLayoutGuide is available (iOS 7+), replace the constraint in this outlet with a version using the Top Layout Guide instead.

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(topLayoutGuide)]) {
    [self.view removeConstraint:self.containerTopSpaceConstraint];

    self.containerTopSpaceConstraint =
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:self.topLayoutGuide
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                multiplier:1
                                  constant:0];

    [self.view addConstraint:self.containerTopSpaceConstraint];

    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Comment: This had the effect of moving my bar at the top of the screen down, which is good, but it also made it so my status bar has a white background instead of a gray background.

Comment: On iOS 7 the status bar background is transparent. Set the background color for your top view (behind the status bar) to whatever color you want the status bar to have.

Comment: I found reset self.view.frame. THX!

Answer (score 6):

For reference, the solution below did work when I applied it to my ViewControllers.  However, it's not ideal and a bit hacky.  If it's the only approach I can take, then so be it, though.

```
float systemVersion=[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
if(systemVersion>=7.0f)
{
    CGRect tempRect;
    for(UIView *sub in [[self view] subviews])
    {
        tempRect = [sub frame];
        tempRect.origin.y += 20.0f; //Height of status bar
        [sub setFrame:tempRect];
    }
}
```

Comment: hey I have used above code but this view comes under navigation bar and i want it to come above navigation bar.Please help if you have any other solution.

Answer (score 5):

Apple are pushing you to use autolayout to accomplish this. You need to set a constraint to the "Top Layout Guide" from the top subview in your view.

See this document for examples:

[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1797/_index.html](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/topLayoutGuide)

To do this without XIBs, you'll need to add the constraint programatically. Apple's docs give a good example of this, which I've summarised below.

Giving that the `topLayoutGuide` is a property on a view controller, you just use it in your dictionary of variable bindings. Then you set up your constraint like normal:

```
id topGuide = [myViewController topLayoutGuide];
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(button, topGuide);
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[topGuide]-20-[button]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
```

The documentation for this can be found [in the `UIViewController` class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/topLayoutGuide).

Comment: You can't set a constraint to the Top Layout Guide from Interface Builder if you are using a XIB, only if you are using a storyboard. So the question remains, how do you create this constraint programmatically?

Comment: @PhillApley See my edited answer for how to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

1)The simplest solution if you don't mind having an opaque navigation bar:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

2) svguerin3's answer can't work in the general case. For example, if one of your subviews uses autosizing to be hooked at the bottom of its container, then its new position will be wrong. And it could go out of screen in the worst case.

Comment: Tried, didn't work. This is probably the most obnoxious problem I've ever had.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
// OR
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 20);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried viewing your XIBs as source and removing any line containing ﻿edgesforextendedlayout ??

We had to remove this line in our storyboard's scenes since our storyboard's scenes' main views are represented by XIBs

What was happening for us was that somehow, in some scenes, the XIB content for the scene's main view was being pushed down by the height of the status bar and the navigation bar.

Removing that line allowed the XIBs to be displayed as if their top originated at the same top of its storyboard's scene.

Sadly, we have no idea what triggered this, but I saw it happen when changing the order of the contents within the XIB's main view so that a UITextView appeared first.  Rearranging the order of items after this was triggered had no effect in removing this unwanted behaviour.

Hope this helps anyone else running into this type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the storyboard, after setting the top layout of your view, you can uncheck the "Under Opaque Bars" in the Attributes Inspector

[image: Storyboard]