# UIViewController content under Status Bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

I want my content to go under status bar. I don't want to show `NavigationBar`. I've checked extend edges 
"Under Top Bars" in storyboard settings and I am facing an issue that it just stops working from no reason. Can I force `ViewController/ NavigationController` content to go under status bar programmatically ?

Thank you

Comment: looks like a duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28367771/extend-uiviewcontrollers-view-without-a-navigation-bar-under-status-bar)

Answer (score -1):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}
```