# How to allow UIView lie under status bar in iOS 10?

Tags: styles, ios10, statusbar

How to allow UIView lie under status bar like on the picture below?

[image]

Comment: try adding top = 0 to masterview.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Originally answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50807874/8408162).

If you're using Safe Area Layout Guides you can do this completely in Interface Builder.

[image]

Pin the view you want under the status bar to the main view using the `Top Space to Container Margin` constraint instead of `Top Space to Safe Area` constraint.

[image]

Then on the Size Inspector for the main view, uncheck Safe Area Relative Margins.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure that you've set your `top space constraint` equals 0 to your `superview`, *not* to the `Bottom Layout Guide` in the Storyboard.

In order to make status bar style like in the screenshot (white text, transparent background) you may want to set it's `style` to `.lightContent`.

Answer (score -5):

> You can set the status bar style to **light content**.

**1. Add this key-val to your .Plist.**

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

**2. In your App Delegate class, add the following to didFinishLaunch method.**

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

Here are the relevant [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740648/how-to-set-status-bar-style-in-swift-3).

Comment: Are you sure there is no way to show UIView below status bar?

Comment: @user3400881 According your question and the image you posted, the status bar can either remain shown or is completely hidden. You could set the style to light to get an effect like shown in your image. Otherwise, set it to any colour you want. By changing the style to .light, you will achieve the desired effect. You could also explore other option it has like .default

Comment: @user3400881 try it and let me know if helps

Comment: Setting color for status bar background is not what I am seeking for. I'll try to find another solution. But thank you for your effort.

Comment: Setting the style to LightContent would make the status bar transparent and whatever background colour your view has would be displayed with text appearing in white. Do try the second approach before exploring further.

Comment: I use this line in AppDelegate which do, I guess, the same UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent .

Comment: Also when I try your code I get this error: Method does not override any method from its superclass. I think it is out of date. Look at the first letter of enum case. It's capital, which means it is written on Swift 2.

Comment: It does make text in status bar white, but status bar is not transperant. It's white

Comment: what is the colour of your view ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151748/discussion-between-umar-farooque-and-user3400881).

Comment: maybe you can add a screenshot of your view .. how it looks in storyboard and on simulator when it runs

Comment: I cant attach screenshot to the comment unfortunattely. Background colour of my view has opacity 0%