# Getting Autolayout beneath the status bar

Tags: ios, cocoa, format, autolayout

I have read multiple previous posts on Autolayout and the status bar behavior in iOS 7 and still do not know how to get my Autolay-ed out objects to be beneath the status bar.

I currently have

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

and a search bar has a visual format applied like `V:|-0-searchBar-|`.

The search bar renders under the status bar like
[image]
as expected.

I have been unable to find a solution to get the search bar to start at the bottom edge of the status bar. How can this be done?

**EDIT:** I have looked at the top layout option, but I have a xib for my Custom View Controller. There is no top layout guide available. How can I support this setup? I would like to avoid checking the system version. 
[image: ib screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to programmatically access the top guide by following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990224/ios7-view-under-status-bar-edgesforextendedlayout-not-working/19242362#19242362). I was using XIBs for my custom class and thus could not access the `topLayoutGuide` through the graphical interface builder as seen below.

[image: ib screenshot]
Instead `topLayoutGuide` can be accessed through `[self topLayoutGuide]`, where self is the `UIViewController`. [Documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/topLayoutGuide)

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(topLayoutGuide)]) {
    id topGuide = [self topLayoutGuide];
    NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(topGuide ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `topLayoutGuide`.

Apple has a great guide on this issue: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1797/_index.html

Comment: Thank you for the link, I tried it before, but I have a xib just for my custom view controller class and there is no `topLayoutGuide` for the xib.